# Decoupled Web APIs on Azure (Architecture Advise)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin, jwt, azure-active-directory

I'm working for a non-profit that is trying to create a collection of services that will allow them to do a few things:

- Create/Manage Users
- Create/Manger Competitions
- Create/Manager Events(a Competition is made up of many Events)
- Logistics
- Etc.

Here are some of the requirements:

- Host on Azure
- Accounts are created using the user's own email address (can be any domain)
- Each service must be independent of each other
- System should be accessible from anywhere(browser, mobile app, etc.)
- Once a user logs in, access to other systems should be available(if needed or depending on permissions)
  -services can talk to each other(we've successfully done a POC on this using Azure Active Directory)

I've spent some time researching the possible ways to tackle this, including looking at articles like this:

http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

It sounds like JWT is the way to go, but I want to make sure that this architecture approach lends itself to flexibility down the road. I'm willing to learn/user any technology as long as it plays along .Net, Web Api, and MVC.

My initial idea was to set each "system" as a Web API, which is pretty straightforward. My concern is authentication/authorization. The million dollar question then becomes:

How can I authenticate a user on a browser/mobile/desktop app and then make use of the other services(APIs), where each service can verify if the user is authenticated independent of other services.

For example, lets say I am using the web app(browser) and register as a user(using User service) in order to register for a competition(Competition service). what kind of technologies/architecture would need to be used for both services to use the same authentication mechanism?

I am not new to MVC or Web API but I am to a scenario like this, so all help or advice is greatly appreciate it. For any that are interested, this is the non-profit: http://worldjumprope.org/

They are doing some cool stuff in terms of outreach and spreading the love for jump rope. Their goal is to be able to help people all around the world and provide a way to for them to come together and compete. They've been doing it for years, growing each year, all for free and out of pure passion for the sport. Help me help them!

Answer (score 1):

Azure Active Directory can help you with your need.

[image]

About the security/Auth mechanism, simply put, it is like you get a token from Azure Active Directory to be able to use it to do authentication for a certain Audiences/Tenants.

And in your architecture, when you acquire a Token, you can specify if you are going to use it against a certain audience or it will work for a list of audiences or all audiences in a specific tenant or in a multi tenant scenario.

Here is a link to a video about AAD Single Sign on:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/overview-of-single-sign-on/

You can download the AAD Solutions arcutecture from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45909

Comment: I forgot to include on my post that User accounts cannot be created in Azure AD. We can do API-to-API through AD which I've done in a POC successfully. My understanding of your proposed solution is that user accounts have to be in AD in order for everything to work. Users register with their own email, not with our domain so that's why we didn't go that route. However, if it's possible to create an account in our Azure AD with the user's email, we would love that! Let me know what you think.

Comment: You can use Azure Graph Api (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/hh974476.aspx) to create users in Azure AD. Then you can encapsulate that functionality in your API to create users with your own API and in the back ground put the user info to Azure AD.

Comment: how would we deal with passwords? Would we just pass them to AD and not even store them?

Answer (score 0):

Also maybe worth looking at Identity Server - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.

Same concept as Azure AD in terms of tokens, but perhaps with greater options for what you choose as a data store for your user information.

There are lots of demos and source code on the site, particularly around the different types of authentication flow \ service to service authentication